# Trying to run rviz: Getting error "Could not contact ROS master..."

Tags: rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to run rviz on electric/Ubuntu 10.4.  I am getting the popup message:

rviz:  Waiting for master
Could not contact ROS master at [http://localhost:11311, retrying...

I've run rviz before and never seen this.  Any assistance is appreciated.
Paul.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11318/trying-to-run-rviz:--getting-error-%22could-not-contact-ros-master...%22/) by [Paul0nc](https://answers.ros.org/users/1067/paul0nc/) on ROS Answers with karma: 271 on 2011-09-26

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Paul0nc](https://answers.ros.org/users/1067/paul0nc/) on 2011-10-02**:
Thanks Hsu.  This worked.

**Comment by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) on 2011-09-26**:
Paul, you can edit your original question, rather than posting an answer.   Is your roscore running and your ROS_MASTER_URI pointing to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try:

In one terminal run "roscore"
Then, in a new terminal do "rosrun rviz rviz"

---

Originally posted by [jrcapriles](https://answers.ros.org/users/269/jrcapriles/) with karma: 370 on 2011-09-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 15

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need some instance of roscore running, either on your machine or externally. One option is what someone else already suggested, which is to roscore in a terminal on your machine.
What we frequently have to do in our lab is to remotely access robot data. In this case, we need to access the instance of roscore running on the robot (PR2, just for reference). In this case set the environment variable ROS_MASTER_URI to the appropriate value. This value is usually http://[name]:11311.

---

Originally posted by [akargol](https://answers.ros.org/users/1025/akargol/) with karma: 126 on 2011-09-27

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Paul0nc](https://answers.ros.org/users/1067/paul0nc/) on 2011-10-02**:
Thanks akargol.  This worked.